# SSL/TSL issue when attempting to post message from C# to Slack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, slack, slack-api

I am attempting to post a message using web hooks through Slack in ASP.NET MVC C#. I am getting a **SSL/TLS issue** when attempting to execute. My code looks great, and I've compared it to several tutorials out there without finding any differences. Here is my SlackClient.cs :

```
public class SlackClient
{
    private readonly Uri _uri;
    private readonly Encoding _encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

    public SlackClient(string urlWithAccessToken)
    {
        _uri = new Uri(urlWithAccessToken);
    }

    //Post a message using simple strings  
    public void PostMessage(string text, string username = null, string channel = null)
    {
        Payload payload = new Payload()
        {
            Channel = channel,
            Username = username,
            Text = text
        };

        PostMessage(payload);
    }

    
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMessage(Payload payload)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        string payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
        var content = new StringContent(payloadJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        { var result = client.PostAsync(_uri, content).Result; return result; }
    }
}

//This class serializes into the Json payload required by Slack Incoming WebHooks  
   public class Payload
   {
    [JsonProperty("channel")]
    public string Channel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is where I actually call the PostMessage (I've hidden by actual webhook address/token for security purposes)

```
   public void SlackMessageTest()
    {

        string WebHookUrl = "https://myslackwebsite.slack.com/services/MYWEBHOOKURLFROMSLACK";             
        SlackClient client = new SlackClient(WebHookUrl);
        client.PostMessage(username: "tester", text: "Testing Slack Integration!", channel: "#random");
        
    }
```

The error I get is as follows:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

So it seems I have an issue with my PostMessage method, with the URI return. From what I've researched, it should just work! My web hook is validated and set up correctly in Slack.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Just a _guess_ since I haven't worked with their API - use `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` as they have [deprecated older TLS](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2019-07-deprecate-early-tls-versions). Hth.

Comment: Please post your comment as a solution! It fixed my problem and id like to give you credit! Tls12 was the answer.

Comment: Cool - done below. Glad it fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slack [requires TLS 1.2 and above](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2019-07-deprecate-early-tls-versions)

That said, replace `SecurityProtocolType.Tls` (TLS 1) with `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`(TLS 1.2)

REF: [SecurityProtocolType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=net-5.0)

Hth.